# How do I pass an object instance inside of a lambda function in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

I want to multi-thread my application, and i have a bit of code that takes a lot of CPU power, and needs to run on another thread.

The problem is that inside the lambda function, i am referencing class variables, so i need to pass in an object instance to the lambda in order to have them inside the function. Here is the lambda:

```
auto detect_thread = []() {
    ...code...
};
```

and then I execute it this way:

```
std::thread matching{ detect_thread };
```

I already tried passing `"this"` as a second argument to the thread, and then loading it as a parameter in the lambda parameter list - `[](ClassName obj) {...}` and then using obj to access the private and public variables, but that threw another error:

```
std::invoke no matching overloaded function found
```

Am i doing something wrong when i'm passing the `this`, should i pass it as a reference or am i doing something wrong with the multi threading itself?

Comment: `this` is a pointer to your class. Argument in your lambda should be `ClassName*  obj`.

Comment: Simply capture `this`. Just make sure that the thread will not outlive the instance. And, that access to that instance member variables is synchronized, or made only from a single thread (if not read-only).

Comment: @all thanks for the info. I missunderstood the docs, and thought i need to pass a this as a reference (&this), which is what was causing the "headache'. I added pointer (*) to the obj, and that solved my problem, but now i have to use -> to access class properties. Any way around that?

Comment: @DimitarVeljanovski Option 1: `MyClass& notPointer = *obj;`. Option 2: Don't pass `obj` at all, capture `this` in the lambda capture list and write your code as if you were still in the member function (see the answer below).

Comment: @DimitarVeljanovski If you capture `this`, you have direct access to member variables (without writing `this->`): [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rZLjwS91coBLZWFr).

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica, Re, "simply capture `this`." That simplifies the source code, but it complicates what happens under the hood. A non-capturing lambda effectively is just a pointer to an anonymous function. (i.e., it's a compile-time constant). A capturing lambda constructs an object each time it is evaluated. Depending on the constraints of the system that somebody is building, and depending on where and when the functional object eventually gets called, that may or may not be a concern.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Might be true, even though optimizers are powerful and may generate the equally-efficient assembly in both cases. However, I would call this way of thinking a premature optimization. Capturing `this` is IMO ideal for the OP's purpose, and I would suggest to use it unless he/she proves (by profiling) that it is less efficient.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Compare both variants in an [exemplary case](https://godbolt.org/z/XnpAB3). The generated assembly is the same. Don't say it will be in all cases, but wouldn't say in advance that there will be any performance difference either, per se. [More complex case with threads](https://godbolt.org/z/mb4zdx), again, same assembly.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica, I did some reading. You are correct when the number of captures is small, but my concern is valid when there's more of them. Seems that `sizeof(std::function<...>)` is _always_ the same. (TBD: always 32?). If the captures from a lambda fit within that size, then they're just copied into the function object when the lambda is evaluated; but if there's too many captures, then a `new` bag-of-holding object is allocated from the heap each time the lambda is evaluated. (Heap allocation is something that I must avoid in the embedded system that I am working on right now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for the multithread part but to get local variables inside your lambda you have to capture them.

Captured variables are inside []. you can by default get everything by ref with

```
[&](){ your code}
```

But since it can lead to capturing way too many things and it looks like you only need this, you should use:

```
[this](){your code}
```

for more infos: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda